# Javascript: Invoke function directly or dispatch event?

Tags: javascript, events

Where we have js code that submits a form instead of just submitting the form like:

```
form.submit();
```

Should we instead dispatch a (bubbling, cancelable) event in order to allow other potential js event listeners the chance to handle the form submission:

```
form.dispatchEvent(new Event('submit', {bubbles: true, cancelable: true}));
```

It seems like this allows our code to play more nicely with others.  If this is true, why isn't this pattern pushed more?

Comment: .submit() does not emit a submit event, and it does not run the onsubmit,  so it depends on your needs, but i would say the second is better

Answer (score 1):

**[HTMLFormElement.requestSubmit()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLFormElement/requestSubmit)** to the rescue!

In most cases in which a form is to be submitted programmatically via JavaScript, it's wise to use `requestSubmit()` rather than `submit()`.  Doing so ensures submit handlers will have a chance to handle the submit event.  Use `submit()` only when you want to explicitly submit the form ignoring any registered submit event listeners and form validation.

I was simply not aware of this newer form method.

See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLFormElement/submit

> The HTMLFormElement.submit() method submits a given `<form>`.
>
> This method is similar, but not identical to, activating a form's
> submit `<button>`. When invoking this method directly, however:
>
> - No submit event is raised. In particular, the form's `onsubmit` event handler is not run.
> - Constraint validation is not triggered.
>
> The `HTMLFormElement.requestSubmit()` method is identical to activating
> a form's submit `<button>` and does not have these differences.

And usage notes from https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLFormElement/requestSubmit

> The obvious question is: Why does this method [`requestSubmit()`] exist, when we've had the `submit()` method since the dawn of time?
>
> The answer is simple. `submit()` submits the form, but that's all it
> does. `requestSubmit()`, on the other hand, acts as if a submit button
> were clicked. The form's content is validated, and the form is
> submitted only if validation succeeds. Once the form has been
> submitted, the submit event is sent back to the form object.

Answer (score 0):

The only problem with answer #1 is requestSubmit is not available in Safari prior to version 16.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34363287)